# Не получается импортировать класс

Tags: python, python-2.x, импорт

Привет.

У меня есть класс `CStatistics`, который необходимо импортировать. Данный класс находится по адресу: `DataUnloader/Statistic/CStatistics.py`

Скрипт, в который должен произойти импорт находится по адресу: `./` (на скрине `Quality`)

Чтобы было понятнее, я прикреплю скрин:

[image: Дерево каталогов]

Проблема в том, что указанный класс не подцепляется. Логично, что нужно сделать так:

```
import DataUnloader.Statistic.SStatistics
```

чтобы его подцепить. Но это не помогает

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452054/pycharm-unresolved-reference-when-importing-class-from-other-file) задавался подобный вопрос. Он совпадает с моим мнением. Но это не помогло решить проблему.

Подскажите, как сделать импорт?

`PyCharm`, в котором я веду разработку, не хочет даже видеть `DataUnloader`:

[image: Пример импорта в PyCharm]

Comment: Эм. У вас в папке лежит "CStatistics" а вы импортируете "SStatistics"

Comment: @Alban Пардон, в скрине ошибка. Но факт в том, что даже `DataUnloader` он не видит.

Comment: @Alban что он сделает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во-первых, в PyCharm можно помечать директорию как [source root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/content-root.html), что позволяет ему видеть директории ниже

во-вторых, я не вижу в Вашей иерархии `__init__.py`-файлов, они нужны, чтобы Python и PyCharm знали, что это не просто директория, а пакет с модулями, без них импорт не сработает как нужно

подробнее [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте следующею конструкцию:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"/путь/к/каталогу/в/котором/лежит/модуль")
import name # Где name название модуля в этом каталоге
```

К примеру есть python файл в который вам необходимо импортировать модуль под названием `My_class`.

Python file лежит на рабочем столе. Модуль также на рабочем толе, но по пути: `/test/test_2/` и содержит в себе следующее:

```
def check():
    print('Im here!')
```

Делаем следующее:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\test_2")
import My_class
My_class.check() # Проверяем
```

Видим что всё работает:

```
Im here!
```